# JavaScript Error for OnClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="DaVincisApp1.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/motion.js"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){     /* make sure the contact form is hidden when the page loads: */     $('div#contact-form').hide();      $('a#contact-button').toggle(function(){         /* slides the contact form down and shows it */         $('div#contact-form').slideDown();     }, function () {         /* hides it again */         $('div#contact-form').slideUp();     } } 
);</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <div id="navigation-primary">
        <ul>
            <li id="contact-button"><a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleSlide('quickcontact');">
                <span>Contact</span></a> </li>
        </ul>
        <h3>
            Contact US</h3>
        <div id="contact-form" style="display: none; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;">
            <form id='freeform' method="post" action="http://WebDev.com/">
            <div class='hiddenFields'>
                <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="20" />
                <input type="hidden" name="URI" value="index" />
                <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="1c46d517779f90c9f5a13bac8338968a3c2b9d16" />
                <input type="hidden" name="status" value="open" />
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="consultation/thank_you" />
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_on_duplicate" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://professional-painters.com/" />
                <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="Quick" />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="freeform" />
                <input type="hidden" name="params_id" value="136390" />
                <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
            </div>
            <fieldset style="padding: 7px;">
                <table id="quickcontact-in">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input tabindex="1" class="field" type="text" name="name" value="Name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Name') this.value = '';"
                                onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Name';" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input tabindex="2" class="field" type="text" name="email" value="Email address"
                                onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email address') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email address';" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input tabindex="3" class="field" type="text" name="phone1" value="Phone (optional)"
                                onfocus="if (this.value == 'Phone (optional)') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Phone';" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <textarea tabindex="4" class="txtField" cols="4" rows="4" name="comments">Questions or Comments</textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                Please enter these letters:
                                <br />
                                <img src="http://professional-painters.com/images/captchas/1297129344.1793.jpg" width="140"
                                    height="30" style="border: 0;" alt=" " /><br />
                                <input tabindex="5" class="field" type="text" name="captcha" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="submit">
                                <input tabindex="6" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="tiny" align="right">
                                <a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleSlide('quickcontact');">Close</a></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#navigation-primary {
/*background: url("/img/nav_back.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #61533F;*/
background-color: Red;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 46px;
z-index: 1;
}

#nav {
height: 34px;
width: 878px;
}

#nav-contact a {
/*background: url("/img/nav_contact.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;*/
background-color: Green;
width: 109px;
}

#quickcontact {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #666449;
border-left: 2px solid #3D352B;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
text-align: left;
top: 75px;
width: 245px;
z-index: 1000;
}

#quickcontact-in a {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#quickcontact fieldset {
border: medium none;
}

#quickcontact-in .field {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FEFBD5;
border: 2px solid #FFF1BD;
color: #666666;
padding: 2px;
width: 190px;
}

#quickcontact-in .txtField {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FEFBD5;
border: 2px solid #FFF1BD;
color: #666666;
display: block;
float: left;
font: 1em "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
height: 90px;
margin: 5px 0 7px;
outline: medium none;
padding: 2px;
width: 190px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the exact same javascript? There is no element with the ID 'nav' in the HTML you provided.

Comment: Change your menu HTML to:
            <li><a href="/link-to-contact-form" id="contact-button"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
You do not need to put onmousedown="" or onclick="" or anything into the <a>

Comment: note: I edited my answer to include required HTML

Comment: When the page loads, the Contact form is open when it should be closed to start off with.  Also what event should I use for the Close Anchor Tag, its at the end of the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I this it would be smart of you to use jquery and do it yourself. It's not that hard at all and the JS code is very short and easy.

First, you need to style the contact form and the menu so it looks the same way as it does when the contact form is expanded. I'm guessing you can actually use the code you already have. But I understand your biggest problem is with the javascript code.

Make sure that the anchor tag has the id: id="contact_button" and that the form is wrapped within a div with the id="contact-form"

So the HTML needs to be something like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/link">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link-2">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link-3">Menuitem 3</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact-button" href="/contact-form">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="contact-form">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Then, to make the contact form show, you need to put jquery on your html page somewhere and you need to place the following code within another .js file or within  tags:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* make sure the contact form is hidden when the page loads: */
    $('div#contact-form').hide();

    $('a#contact-button').toggle(function(){
        /* slides the contact form down and shows it */
        $('div#contact-form').slideDown();
    }, function () {
        /* hides it again */
        $('div#contact-form').slideUp();
    }
}
```

That's it. As for the code to actually send the email using .net you can maybe follow this tutorial:

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/email/email-aspnet2-vb.aspx

Comment: +1, This is more sensible than trying to figure out the existing script.

Comment: No, exactly the opposite. If you don't know anything about javascript, this is the better way forward. Because you can simply copy and paste this code and it will work. However, with the other example, copied from motion.js, you will have to make your document completely the same as the original site and you'll have to make complicated javascript modifictions to the original js.. 
In other words: This is the simplest way for you to get the functionality that you need.

Comment: You mentioned "you need to put jquery on your html page" which JQuery should I include? /jquery-1.4.1.min.js  ?

Comment: anyone.. this will work in all versions. I would just use the latest one, jquery 1.5:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this, so I'm not certain about it, but it's probably right:

`sfHover` is defined thusly:

```
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
```

Take a close look at this line:

```
document.getElementById("nav")
```

It's looking for an element with an `id` of `nav` - in your "prototype HTML", you do not have an element with that `id`.

You don't appear to have any need for `sfHover` in your "prototype HTML", so you should just get rid of the entire function. If you do need it, you need to change `nav` into an `id` you actually have in your HTML (or change an `id` in your HTML to `nav`).

Comment: I added the div id="nav" and commented the function SFHover, still get the same error, in fact the whole page crashes.

Comment: If you commented out the function `sfHover`, how can you still get an error about `sfHover`? Something doesn't add up here.

Comment: Did you comment out this line also? `if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);`

Comment: the error indicates this is not defined on line 145: em.style.setExpression('width', 'minmax_checkFont()');

Comment: Yes I commented that line as well

Comment: Well, we've got past one error, and now you have a different one.

Comment: Yea, someone else said that this JavaScript was poorly written.  Even JQuery is included in their site, but not even used.

Comment: Unfortunately, that error doesn't make any sense to me. I would assume the `minmax.js` part of your file would "just work". I don't know why you're getting that error.

Comment: This is a slightly sucky suggestion, but try getting rid of everything in that file past this line: `// minmax.js: make IE5+/Win support CSS min/max-width/height`. It'll only affect IE6 and older browsers, which most people no longer care about - `min-height` works in IE7+.

Comment: what I dont get is that this runs perfectly fine on the aformentioned site.  I've checked all their other .js files, and it looks like I dont need anything else.

Comment: I tried getting rid of that as well, with the same error and page crash.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Like before, how can it complain about an error on a line you've deleted?

Comment: It sure is commented  em.style.setExpression('width', 'minmax_checkFont()');
  but says its not implemented

Comment: I can't really help any more unless I can test exactly what you have. Could you make your style/script includes inline (`<style type="text/css">..</style>` / `<script type="text/javascript">..</script>`), make sure it's still not working and then edit your question with the entire code?

Comment: I guess theres no trick to indent copied code 4 spaces. well its all there.  Like I said I checked professional-painters.com and they have a couple of additonal .js files, but I dont think they are related.

Comment: I'll look at this again tomorrow, if it's not sorted by then. It's 4am in the morning here, I need to get some sleep :)